# Replace more than one word in a column with R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I trying to change the all the names with the word stocker in job.tittle to a new column job.title.2
I tried to use gsub() without the expected result

My data.frame looks liek this:

x<- data.frame(Job.tittle=c("DW Overnight Stockers", "Checkers","TH Stockers", "CM Midland Stockers"), Head.counts=c(100,50,100,200))

Thank you

I tried this: x$job.tittle.2<-gsub("\bDW Overnight Stockers\w+","Stocker",x$Job.tittle)
and did not work

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Using regex, this takes a string that contains the word "stocker" or "stockers", in either upper or lower case, any where in the string, and replaces it with "Stocker".

```
x$job.title.2 <- gsub(".*stockers?.*", "Stocker", x$Job.tittle, ignore.case = TRUE) 
x
```

```
             Job.tittle Head.counts job.title.2
1 DW Overnight Stockers         100     Stocker
2              Checkers          50    Checkers
3           TH Stockers         100     Stocker
4   CM Midland Stockers         200     Stocker
```